# Unordered List Badge/Count Label

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to create a badge/count label on the right-hand side of an unordered list, similar to Facebook (shown below - the badge next to **Messages**):

[image]

Ideally, I would like to do this entirely in CSS without the need for images. I am familiar with creating a div with the relevant corner radius, etc. to give the slightly rounded effect, but I am unsure of the best and most elegant way to position the element on the right-hand side and have it associated specifically with that list item (for identification purposes in the CSS).

Thanks in advance for any guidance/assistance.

Comment: Please post the html & css you have tried so far to achieve the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Put label and count in one div. then use float:right; to count and float:left to label (if label has div itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item <span>3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span>3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span>3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span>3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span>3</span></li>
    <li>Item <span>3</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 300px;
}

span {
    background: #ccc;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sBJ8y/

Comment: just hide the ul text-decoration :) to hide the balls. (i don't know how they're called >.<

Answer (score 0):

Just do this little code. To remove the bullots from the list element write
ul li{ list-style:none;}